# Heroku: Get localhost net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when app deployed

Tags: multithreading, heroku, flask, httpserver, plotly-dash

I am running a `app.py` which has two threads, one for the dash app, and the other for `HTTPServer`.

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div( ... )
@app.callback( ... )
def do_something( ... ): ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=app.run_server, kwargs={'debug': False})
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

The reason to run `HTTPServer` is to retrieve local files with url `'localhost:8000/audios/%s.wav' % clicked_index`, and use the url as the `src` for `html.Audio`. Particularly, I have `.wav` files in local `audios/`, and `callback` enables hover and triggers audio playback.

It runs without a problem locally with `python app.py`, but it does not on the deployed app - the hover only triggers *part of the audios*. In the screenshot, the data point with the hovered info `Piano` correctly play the audio, but we can see `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` for other `'localhost:8000/audios/%s.wav' % clicked_index` in the right bottom which don't play audio. This doesn't happen locally.

When I check the files with `heroku run bash --app myapp`, all wav files are there in the `audios/`.

And if I run `python -m http.server 8000` locally, the deployed app runs without problem; no missing audio playback.

I appreciate anyone who enlightens me in this subject which I just started.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3, Heroku seems to be unable to host static files, and the s3 public bucket satisfies my need.